# Strictfp returns different results on different systems

Tags: java, floating-point, strictfp

I'm using the following method on Windows 8 (Intel Atom Z3775):

```
public static strictfp void main(String args[])
{
    float a = 0.000000002f;
    float b = 90000300000000004f;
    float c = a * b;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

which gives me:  1.80000592E8

When running

```
public strictfp void calculate()
{
    float a = 0.000000002f;
    float b = 90000300000000004f;
    float c = a * b;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

i get: 1.8000059E8

Why do they differ? Am I using strictfp wrong?

Comment: What happens if you print `String.format("%08x", Float.floatToIntBits(c))` instead in both cases?

Comment: They return exactly the same string. Using Float.toString(c) to convert to String on both plaforms doesn't help.

Comment: Right - so the actual numbers are bitwise-identical. There is simply a difference in the implementation of the algorithm for turning the float into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confirmed that printing the hex representation of the floats shows that the values are the same:

```
String.format("%08x", Float.floatToIntBits(c))
```

This means that there is a difference in the implementation of how a `float` is converted to a `String`.

Notice that the [OpenJDK implementation of `java.lang.Float.toString(float)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Float.java/#205) invokes a method from `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal` - i.e. it is a JDK-specific implementation.

You'd need either:

- To ensure that you always run the code using the same implementation
- To provide your own implementation which always produces the same result
- To specify a shorter format, so that the strings are the same to that many decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the displaying method certainly differs...

Comment: And that changes what? I now added a '+ " "' to System.out.println() and now both floats are first converted to a string before being given to the method.

Comment: Obviously the float to string conversion also can differ.

Comment: @user2912528 you'd have to implement the float to string conversion yourself.